# Is there a utility for hopping in and out of a CLI?

Tags: command-line, administration, nohup

Lets say I've got a bit of server software. I start it up and it provides an interface on stdin/stdout that I can use to enter commands during runtime. I want to be able to start it up over SSH, exit the session, come back and hook right back into that stdin/stdout interface again.

I was thinking there must be an easy command like nohup or & that would allow me to do this. Is there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use can use `tmux` or, the older `screen`. The following are excerpts of their respective `man` pages:

1. `tmux`:

   ```
    tmux is a terminal multiplexer: it enables a number of terminals to be
    created, accessed, and controlled from a single screen.  tmux may be
    detached from a screen and continue running in the background, then later
    reattached.

    When tmux is started it creates a new session with a single window and
    displays it on screen.  A status line at the bottom of the screen shows
    information on the current session and is used to enter interactive
    commands.

    A session is a single collection of pseudo terminals under the management
    of tmux.  Each session has one or more windows linked to it.  A window
    occupies the entire screen and may be split into rectangular panes, each
    of which is a separate pseudo terminal (the pty(4) manual page documents
    the technical details of pseudo terminals).  Any number of tmux instances
    may connect to the same session, and any number of windows may be present
    in the same session.  Once all sessions are killed, tmux exits.

    Each session is persistent and will survive accidental disconnection
    (such as ssh(1) connection timeout) or intentional detaching (with the
    'C-b d' key strokes).  tmux may be reattached using:

          $ tmux attach
   ```
2. `screen`

   ```
      Screen  is  a  full-screen  window  manager that multiplexes a physical
      terminal between  several  processes  (typically  interactive  shells).
      Each  virtual  terminal  provides the functions of a DEC VT100 terminal
      and, in addition, several control functions from the ISO 6429 (ECMA 48,
      ANSI X3.64) and ISO 2022 standards (e.g. insert/delete line and support
      for multiple character sets).  There is a scrollback history buffer for
      each virtual terminal and a copy-and-paste mechanism that allows moving
      text regions between windows.

      When screen is called, it creates a single window with a  shell  in  it
      (or  the  specified  command) and then gets out of your way so that you
      can use the program as you normally would.  Then, at any time, you  can
      create new (full-screen) windows with other programs in them (including
      more shells), kill existing windows,  view  a  list  of  windows,  turn
      output  logging  on  and off, copy-and-paste text between windows, view
      the scrollback history, switch between windows in whatever  manner  you
      wish,  etc.  All  windows  run their programs completely independent of
      each other. Programs continue to run when their window is currently not
      visible  and  even  when  the whole screen session is detached from the
      user's terminal.  When a program terminates, screen (per default) kills
      the  window  that  contained it.  If this window was in the foreground,
      the display switches to the previous window; if none are  left,  screen
      exits.
   ```

Both of these programs will enable you to log on to a server, launch a process, then log off and leave it running. When you want to check on it, you log back on to the server and reconnect to the running `tmux` or `screen` session and it is as though you never left. You can install both of them from the Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install tmux
```

You can find a nice Q&A comparing the two programs on our sister site, [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/549/22222).